# {|Form.Title|} not displaying form title in email subject of a custom sitefinity form

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sitefinity, sitefinity-8

I am trying to show my sitefinity form title in my response email subject [like this solution](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/incomplete-how-to-customize-the-default-subject-line-in-form-responses-email-notification).

When I use {|Form.Title|} in my subject it prints as it is without fetching the actual title. I am directly updating the subject column in my sql server database using the below query

```
UPDATE [sf_notif_msg_template] SET [subject] = '{|Form.Title|}' WHERE [id] = '9FC119BA-FD37-6072-98E5-FF000022C5F7';
```

I have searched on the limited sitefinity forums but no help.

**EDIT :** {|Form.Title|} works perfectly fine in email body and prints the actual form title

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried {|FormDescription.Title|} instead of {|Form.Title|}?  The image from the knowledgebase article you provided appears to show that in the column (red box in image).

[Knowledgebase image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LB0K.png)

Comment: Yes i have tried that too still shows as it is. {|Form.Title|} is there in email body there it fetches the actual title